# Python opencv Aruco "No module named 'cv2.aruco'"

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, python-import, aruco

I am running an Ubuntu virtual machine with, Python 3.6.1, Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit). I am trying to run [the code on this website](http://www.philipzucker.com/aruco-in-opencv/). 
When I try to use

`import cv2.aruco`

I get:

```
>>> import cv2.aruco
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2.aruco'
```

Is this something I need to install or setup?

Comment: I haven't used aruco but with a quick search it seems like it's in the opencv_contrib and not the main opencv. So it depends if you included opencv_contrib in your build.

Comment: @ROAR, wow that was an easy fix, thank you!

Comment: If someone comes looking for the solution: [https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-contrib-python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-contrib-python)

Comment: @MaxMullin I'm going to write this as an official answer

Comment: @ArashRohani It was not in opencv-contirb-python as well

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If `cv2.aruco` is not found, try installing `opencv-contrib-python`, such as by running the following (for the default Python installation):

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

Or for a specific Python installation (in this case Python 3)

```
python3 -m pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

Then try re-running the script trying to access `cv2.aruco`.

Comment: FYI for other readers, the aruco module is not in opencv but  in opencv_contrib module, which is why you need to install this package.

Answer (score 32):

If `cv2.aruco` is not found, first make sure that `opencv-python` is not installed.

for that you can use:

```
pip uninstall opencv-python
```

Then install:

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

We are uninstalling opencv-python because installing two packages of opencv will contradict each other and will not let the other one install.

Answer (score 27):

In my case both `opencv-python` and `opencv-contrib-python` were installed when I was getting the above error.

So I uninstalled opencv-python using

```
pip uninstall opencv-python
```

Run the program and same error. Then I uninstalled opencv-contrib-python

```
pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python
```

After that I reinstalled opencv-contrib-python using

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

And run the program, no error now. So I upvoted both the above answers :)

Answer (score 5):

In case you still need opencv-python for other applications, do the following (in this order, using pip or pip3):

```
pip3 uninstall opencv-python
pip3 uninstall opencv-contrib-python
pip3 install opencv-python
pip3 install opencv-contrib-python
```

If you reverse the last two operations, you will still have the error message.

Answer (score 5):

This version will fix the issue

```
pip uninstall python-opencv opencv-contrib-python opencv-python 
pip install --upgrade opencv-contrib-python==3.4.2.17
```

Other answers do not mention versions, that's why they won't be able to fix this issue.
cv2.aruco is no longer present in newer versions

Answer (score 3):

I had both `opencv-python` and `opencv-contrib-python` installed in my case when I came across this problem. I've tried `pip uninstall opencv-python` but the error still appeared. The following command fixed my issue.

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python-headless
```

There's probably some version conflix so maybe you should try to uninstall and reinstall certain packages to see which one works. I reinstalled `opencv-python` after installing `opencv-contrib-python-headless` and the error did not appear.

Answer (score 2):

BEWARE: `opencv-python` version >4.7.0 have now integrated the `cv2.aruco` module from `opencv-contrib-python`, as marked [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/22986/files#diff-09508dfcb283f5b8f2e58538584a58ce28d369f8c7e23705f004f7d15e6f40e9). Therefore, you're not required to handle these two conflicting dependencies. YAY!

There were some code-breaking changes in the `aruco` module API between 4.6 and 4.7 OpenCV, but these can be easily resolved. This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74964527/attributeerror-module-cv2-aruco-has-no-attribute-dictionary-get) helps point out the differences, it's quite minimal.