# OpenCV aruco not working in Python (windows)

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio, opencv, aruco

I've been doing some work using aruco with c++ but I'll have to switch to python now.

(I'm using windows 8, 64-bit Operating System, x64-based processor)

I installed Python and the libraries I believe I'll need the following way:

- Downloaded and installed Python 3.5 from this link:
  https://www.python.org/downloads/
- Added Python to paths
- Downloaded  opencv+contrib & numpy & scipy from this link:
  https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
- Went to Python Scripts folder in a cmd window and with pip3.5
  installed all the libraries

When I run visual studio I'm able to import numpy and cv2, it's just when I try to import aruco or import cv2.aruco that I have problems...

I honestly just started trying to use python and I must say that I don't really know what I'm doing. I don't have a lot of experience with this kind of stuff (I'm a mechanical egineer student and I'm trying to use computer vision for some stuff, so I pretty much learned everything online). I managed to do what I wanted with c++, but the guys I work with want to make everything with python (they have their reasons).

Also (and again, I'm just trying everything I can here...) when I run python on a cmd window I'm able to import numpy, scipy, cv2 and cv2.aruco.

Am I doing something wrong or do I need something else to use aruco with python?

Any help is appreciated, I'm really running out of googling power haha

Comment: Can you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45972357/python-opencv-aruco-no-module-named-cv2-aruco

Answer (score 0):

maybe try pip install opencv-python

Answer (score 0):

Try also installing the AruCo library through pip just in case, as the environment you have shared does not explicitly have AruCo in it.
`pip install aruco`
Here's the link in PyPI: https://pypi.org/project/aruco/