# How to get Aruco pose estimation in OpenCV Python?

Tags: python, opencv, aruco

I'm following [this](https://betterprogramming.pub/getting-started-with-aruco-markers-b4823a43973c) tutorial on getting started with aruco markers.

I want to get the pose estimation frame axis and display it ontop of the aruco marker like so:

[image]

Here is the relevant code snippet from the tutorial:

```
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    detector = cv2.aruco.ArucoDetector(arucoDict, arucoParams)
        (corners, ids, rejected) = detector.detectMarkers(gray)
    
    if len(corners) > 0:
        for i in range(0, len(ids)):
        
        rvec, tvec, markerPoints = cv2.aruco.estimatePoseSingleMarkers(corners[i], 0.02, mtx, dist)
        cv2.drawFrameAxes(frame, mtx, dist, rvec, tvec, 0.02)
```

But I get the following attributional error:

```
AttributeError: module 'cv2.aruco' has no attribute 'estimatePoseSingleMarkers'
```

My python version: 3.11.2
OpenCV version: 4.7.0

How do I get the pose and draw them in the aruco marker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing an older version of opencv-contrib-python solves the issue.

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python==4.6.0.66
```

You might have to uninstall existing opencv and opencv-contrib-python before that to avoid conflicts: [Python opencv Aruco "No module named 'cv2.aruco'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45972357/python-opencv-aruco-no-module-named-cv2-aruco)

So,

```
pip uninstall opencv-python -y
pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python -y
```

followed by

```
 pip install opencv-contrib-python==4.6.0.66
```

should work.

You can look into the latest build for any changes:
https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

 ARUCO_DICT = {
"DICT_4X4_1000": cv2.aruco.DICT_4X4_1000,
"DICT_5X5_1000": cv2.aruco.DICT_5X5_1000,
"DICT_6X6_1000": cv2.aruco.DICT_6X6_1000,
"DICT_7X7_1000": cv2.aruco.DICT_7X7_1000,
"DICT_ARUCO_ORIGINAL": cv2.aruco.DICT_ARUCO_ORIGINAL,
"DICT_APRILTAG_16h5": cv2.aruco.DICT_APRILTAG_16h5,
"DICT_APRILTAG_25h9": cv2.aruco.DICT_APRILTAG_25h9,
"DICT_APRILTAG_36h10": cv2.aruco.DICT_APRILTAG_36h10,
"DICT_APRILTAG_36h11": cv2.aruco.DICT_APRILTAG_36h11
 }

def detect_markers(image):

aruco_type_list = []

for aruco_type, dictionary_id in ARUCO_DICT.items():

    arucoDict = cv2.aruco.getPredefinedDictionary(dictionary_id)
    arucoParams = cv2.aruco.DetectorParameters()

    corners, ids, _ = cv2.aruco.detectMarkers(image, arucoDict, parameters=arucoParams)

    if len(corners) > 0:
        
        aruco_type_list.append(aruco_type)
        
        print(f"Markers detected using {aruco_type} dictionary")

        for markerCorner, markerId in zip(corners, ids.flatten()):
            corners_aruco = markerCorner.reshape((4, 2))
            (topLeft, topRight, bottomRight, bottomLeft) = corners_aruco

            cv2.polylines(image, [markerCorner.astype(int)], True, (0, 255, 0), 2)

            cX = int((topLeft[0] + bottomRight[0]) / 2)
            cY = int((topLeft[1] + bottomRight[1]) / 2)

            cv2.circle(image, (cX, cY), 5, (255, 0, 0), -1)
            cv2.putText(image, str(aruco_type) + " " + str(int(markerId)),
                        (int(topLeft[0] - 5), int(topLeft[1])), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.5, (255, 0, 255))

        # break  # Stop iterating once markers are detected        
    # cv2.imshow("Detected Markers", image)
        
return aruco_type_list

def pose_estimation(frame, aruco_dict_type, matrix_coefficients, 
distortion_coefficients):

aruco_dict = cv2.aruco.getPredefinedDictionary(aruco_dict_type)
parameters = cv2.aruco.DetectorParameters()

corners, ids, rejected = cv2.aruco.detectMarkers(image, aruco_dict, parameters=parameters)

if len(corners) > 0:
    for i in range(0, len(ids)):
       
        rvec, tvec, markerPoints = cv2.aruco.estimatePoseSingleMarkers(corners[i], 0.025, matrix_coefficients, distortion_coefficients)
        
        cv2.aruco.drawDetectedMarkers(frame, corners) 

        cv2.drawFrameAxes(frame, matrix_coefficients, distortion_coefficients, rvec, tvec, 0.01) 
         
return frame

if __name__ == "__main__":

image_path = r"arucoMarkers/singlemarkersoriginal.jpg"

intrinsic_camera = np.array(((933.15867, 0, 657.59), (0, 933.1586, 400.36993), (0, 0, 1)))
distortion = np.array((-0.43948, 0.18514, 0, 0))

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while cap.isOpened():
    ret, image = cap.read()

    for aruco_type in detect_markers(image):
         image = pose_estimation(image, ARUCO_DICT[aruco_type], intrinsic_camera, distortion)
         
    cv2.imshow('Estimated Pose', image)
            
    if cv2.waitKey(50) & 0xFF == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

https://github.com/Ritabrata-Chakraborty/ArUco/blob/main/Aruco_Detection.py