# Aruco syntax in opencv has changed and I don't know how to access all the functions

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, aruco

I am writing a simple application (or at least so I thought) which is meant to utilize ArUco markers to detect a difference in height between two objects. However, during my tutorial hunt, I realized that previously used command:

```py
cv2.aruco
```

is no longer working (at least on my laptop). I have just spent 4 hours trying to find a solution on the web and can't. I would greatly appreciate someone who could point to the right place in the documentation.

Let me just say, I KNOW the ArUco module was integrated with "objdetect" module but the documentation there still uses the "cv2.aruco" syntax which doesn't work for me. I am referring to this [webpage](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/de/d67/group__objdetect__aruco.html)

As I mentioned before I looked into the documentation but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python opencv Aruco "No module named 'cv2.aruco'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45972357/python-opencv-aruco-no-module-named-cv2-aruco) (found by Googling for “python opencv aruco module”, this was the top hit).

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install --upgrade opencv-contrib-python
```

then

```
pip install opencv-python
```

The following will work:

```
from cv2 import aruco
```

Comment: Should I first uninstall both opencv packages?

Comment: I think it should be better. I just tried it and `from cv2 import aruco` is still working.

Comment: I'll try it tomorrow bc I'm about to go to bed. I have tried to reinstall the packages a couple of times and it didn't work, but I'll try it the way you recommend.

Comment: I am using python 3.9. Please check that also in case. Good night.

Comment: I believe that is the same for me but I will double check. Thank you!

Comment: Ok I did what you suggested and the functions seem to be there, but the autocomplete suggestions in VS Code don't seem to know about them. The output corrects me when I do something wrong though. It looks like it's there just the editor ignores it when giving hints.